# How to properly handle update/delete operations in a RDBMS?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, cascade

I recently designed my first relational database in MySQL, using InnoDB as the engine for all of my tables. I would like to know how to properly handle `DELETE` and `UPDATE` operations when you have many-to-one relationships.

**Example**

Let's say you have the following tables:

**t1**
PK    t1_ID
FK    t2_ID
        A

**t2**
PK    t2_ID
FK    t3_ID
FK    t4_ID

**t3**
PK    t3_ID
        B

**t4**
PK    t4_ID
        C

With those tables, a cascade on delete operation is specified for the FK in `t1` and for both FKs in `t2`. If one or more records are deleted from `t3` or `t4` the corresponding records in `t2` and `t1` are also deleted.

**Questions**

The delete functionality that I need is the reverse. I want the following to occur:

1. Delete a record in `t1`
2. Delete the corresponding record in `t2`
3. If the corresponding record in `t3` is not used anywhere else, i.e. that `t3_ID` is not anywhere else in `t2`, delete the corresponding record in `t3`
4. Repeat step 3 for `t4`

I also need a similar functionality for the update operations.

1. If the record in `t3`/`t4` has no other entries in `t2`, then the
   value can simply be changed.
2. If the record in `t3`/`t4` is in at least one other record in t2, a
   new record will need to be created in `t3`/`t4` and the reference in
   `t2` will need to be updated.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Deleting all the references in `t2` doesn't necessarily make the items in `t3` and `t4` irrelevant. You might add new references to them later. E.g. if `t3` and `t4` are car parts, and `t1` is car models, you might discontinue all models that use them, but add a new model in the future that uses the same parts.

Comment: @Barmar, that's a very good point. I did not think of that. In my actual situation, I am storing measured data points. In certain cases, the values will be the same, but I will also have a number of situations where having repeated values is unlikely. I figured it would be "best" to clean up the database, rather than leave the data in there, on the off chance that it will be used again. Note that this becomes especially important for one table, as those values are used to populate fields in an application that I have developed, thus fields without corresponding data should be removed.

Comment: The real answer to much of this is that it depends on the application and what the data represents, there's no general answer. Especially the part about handling updates: whether you should create new entries or modify the old ones depends on the semantics of the data.

Comment: True; so assuming I were to handle the operations as I outlined, above, how would I go about doing that? Is there anyway to detect when a record no longer has a FK pointing to it or do I need to manually handle this? I could do something like periodically check the references in the lowest-level tables; however, this would be a somewhat costly operation.

Comment: @Slayer537 I'm a little confused by some of your statements - they seem to contradict the model you have supplied in your question. Specifically: _"If one or more records were deleted from t1, the relating records in t2 would also be deleted."_ is not true according to your model (the cascade should happen in the opposite direction: when `t2` is deleted it cascades to `t1`). Perhaps you are using a non-standard FK notation - is `t1` really referencing `t2` (or is it the other way around)?

Comment: @Slayer537 Also: _"No cascading operations are specified on t2, because other records in t1 may relate to records in t3 and/or t4."_ - acording to your model, `t1` doesn't reference `t3` nor `t4` at all (aside from indirect connection through `t2`). Please clarify how exactly _"t1 may relate to records in t3 and/or t4"_.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic, `t1` is indirectly related to `t3`/`t4` through `t2`. I just retested the cascade on delete, it appears I was mistaken, before and the deletes happen in the reverse direction. I was confused, as the model I was using is different than the one shown, above. I will revise my question, appropriately. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I think I now better understand what you need. You are trying to enforce the "one to **one** or many" (instead of the usual "one to zero or many"). You can't do that declaratively in a database that doesn't support deferred FKs, but you can do something along the lines of what  [Barmar proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20850314/533120).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To propagate the deletion, you could do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_unused_t2 AFTER DELETE on t1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF old.t2_ID NOT IN (SELECT t2_ID FROM t1)
    THEN BEGIN
        DELETE FROM t2
        WHERE t2.t2_ID = old.t2_ID;
    END;
    END IF;
END
```

If you want to do it periodically rather than in a trigger, you could do:

```
DELETE FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1 USING (t2_ID)
WHERE t1_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: I think this will work. The propagation I am most concerned about would be deleting from `t3` and `t4` after a delete in `t1`, but I think I should be able to go from here. I'll test this out, tomorrow, and make this the accepted answer, if it works. Thanks!!

Comment: This worked, as desired for the delete operations. There were some minor syntax problems, but I corrected those. Thanks!